# Is My Description of Systems of Equations Correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, logic, systems-of-equations, solution-verification

I am trying to summarize the concept of systems of equations for a written piece in a formal setting for students. For this, I attempt to give a formal and complete description of the case where we wish to determine the complete solution (that is, the one-solution case) for the system and the proof that to solve such a system we need as many equations as variables.

My question is, is the description I provide valid and complete? Also, as part of that requirement, is the proof that I give also valid and complete?

What I have so far follows, which starts with an example for motivation.

> Any single valid equation in one variable addresses exactly one concern. So if we were
>   asked the following question, we would have no way of answering it.
>
> > If a car can drive four times the amount of fuel it's carrying in
> >     gallons minus three times the number of minutes it has spent standing
> >     running idly at traffic lights and we know that a particular car drove
> >     for one hundred miles after a refuel, how much fuel did the car start
> >     with and how many minutes did it spend running idly since it refueled?
>
> The reason being that we are trying to address two concerns with one
>   equation.
>
> The above scenario is precisely the reason that a
>   formal method was developed to discern the various quantities which
>   may be modeled analytically. As we just discussed, in order to be able
>   to successfully and accurately represent the information being
>   queried, the number of equations must somehow be adjusted to account
>   for an increase in the number of variables being used.
>
> How do we know exactly how many equations are required to correctly
>   derive the needed information? And, how do we use the various
>   equations to this end? Finally, do the equations need to satisfy
>   certain properties individually and collectively?
>
> When we attempt to determine what quantities are represented by the
>   given equations and variables, we must keep in mind the following.
>
> 1. All of the variables being used must be related with each of the other
>      variables.
> 2. The number of equations given must at least be "distinct,"
>      consistent, and match the number of variables.
>
> Why are these two rules necessary?
>
> For the first, if the variables we are solving for aren't related,
>   then the situation isn't much different than solving various different
>   unrelated equations simultaneously.
>
> As for the second, while the example with the car we covered above
>   should provide a fairly intuitive understanding of why that is so, a
>   more formal treatment may be summarized as follows.
>
> Consider that a single equation in a single variable describes the
>   relationship between the constants and that variable present in the
>   equation. If we added another variable but left the number of
>   equations unchanged, the new equation is true conditionally for the
>   specific simultaneous choices for both variables. If we added another
>   equation (also relating the two variables across the system) which is
>   distinct (not a multiple of the original) and consistent (doesn't
>   contradict the first and isn't contradictory in itself), we will now
>   have two valid equations in a valid system which fully describes the
>   relation between both variables. In other words, for two related real
>   variables $x$ and $y,$ we have that
>
> $$\begin{align} a_1x + a_2y &= c_1 \tag{1}\\ a_3x + a_4y &= c_2 \end{align}$$
>
> where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are real numbers, $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$ are
>   all non-zero real numbers such that the system $(1)$ is a valid
>   system and furthermore, for some non-zero real constant $m,\ a_1 = ma_3, a_2 = ma_4, \text{ and } c_1 = mc_2$ doesn't happen
>   simultaneously.
>
> Without loss of generality, we can assume that at least $a_1$ and
>   $a_4$ are non-zero. Thus this system may be solved as such.
>
> $$\begin{align} x &= (c_1 - a_2y)/a_1 \tag{2}\\ y &= (c_2 - a_3x)/a_4\end{align}$$
>
> And in this way, we obtained a complete solution to the system since
>   either both $a_2$ and $a_3$ are zero, or, one of the solutions to
>   the variables can be substituted back into the equation other than the
>   one we got the value to substitute from with, allowing us to solve for
>   the other variable.
>
> Let us now assume, by the principle of induction, that this property
>   holds for $n-1$ equations representing $n-1$ variables, $n$
>   being an integer greater than one. This tells us that that at least
>   those many coefficients are non-zero that are required for the system
>   to be valid are present. That is, at least those many variables are
>   present in the system in the same manner as in $(2)$ to allow us to
>   solve for the $n-1$ variables in the $n-1$ equation system.
>
> If we now add one more variable across the system and corresponding
>   valid equation to this system and make the justified assumption that
>   at least the coefficient multiplying the new variable is non-zero in
>   at least the new equation, we may solve for this new variable in terms
>   of all the other variables in the new equation. And since according to
>   the prior assumption that we already have the complete solution to the
>   $n-1$ equation system, we know the value of every other variable
>   already and can use that information to compute the value of the new
>   variable from the rearranged form of the new equation. Thus, a valid
>   completely solvable $n-1$ system assures the complete solution to
>   the valid $n$ equation system in $n$ variables.

I am really truly very grateful for any help on this. Thank you so much for reading through what I have written and providing feedback.

Sincerely,

ThisIsNotAnId

Comment: It is good that you're thinking about this in detail, but what do you mean by a *valid* equation or system? Your use of induction isn't quite clear to me. Adding on one more equation to a system of $n-1$ equations/unknowns with a unique solution doesn't guarantee that the new $n \times n$ system has a solution.

Comment: Another "issue" I have with the use of induction and generalizing from the two equation case is that, from a pedagogical point of view, it might suggest that linear independence is a "pairwise" thing -- which it is in the case of two vectors, but it is not in the general case. That is, in general, to check linear independence, it is not enough to check that vectors are "pairwise independent" ($v_i \neq m v_j$ for $i \neq j$).

Comment: Hi @twosigma , thanks for replying. By a valid equation I mean any equation which is not linearly dependent on any of the other equations in the system, ins't contradictory in itself, and consistent with the rest of the system. For the guarantee of the solution, I think I have to describe a proper restriction or re-think the approach. I will get back to you soon on that. For your second point, I agree. I will make that point clear and distinct in my final revision.

Comment: In my (normative) opinion, I'd prefer just providing examples for motivation, but as for the proof/formal justification part, I'd say "that's one purpose/application of studying linear algebra and its application to matrices and systems of linear equations". So I personally might foreshadow the formal justification by mentioning concepts like "linear independence" and "rank", then leave the formal justification for after we've learned those concepts. That's kind of what those concepts/definitions are for: they capture the ideas we want to, and that's a big reason for why they're the standard.

Comment: @twosigma I think you make a very good point. It seems best to take this route. If you provide this as an answer, I can select it as the accepted solution. Thank you so much for helping out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think examples are good for motivation, but I personally might leave the formal justification and “proof writeup” for after we've learned concepts such as linear independence, rank, and elementary row operations (and you can mention this at the start, as a foreshadowing/preview of things to come). After all, that's kind of what those concepts/definitions are for and why they are the standard: they capture the ideas we want to capture.

For example, to justify that the $n \times n$ system $Ax = b$ has a unique solution if and only if the rows of $A$ are linearly independent, we can do it as follows:

Suppose the rows are linearly independent. Note that elementary row operations don’t change the set of solutions, so we may set out to reduce the matrix in an attempt to find the solutions of our system. Furthermore, they don’t change the row space, so the RREF of $A$ must be the identity matrix (otherwise we get a zero row, which implies fewer than $n$ linearly independent rows in the row space, contradicting the assumption of linear independence). In other words, we get a unique solution.

Conversely, if the rows are linearly dependent, then after row-reduction some row must be zero (otherwise we get $n$ linearly independent row vectors, contradicting the assumption of linear dependence). In particular, this means there is at least one free variable, so either our system has no solution or infinitely many solutions. In particular, it cannot have a unique solution.

However, there might be a nice way to explain all this in simple layman terms, but I don't know how to do it beyond saying something like "the equations have to be independent in a sense; no one can be written as a linear combination of the others. Otherwise, we will have some degree of freedom (an underdetermined system), meaning there cannot be a unique solution."

Comment: This answers my question very nicely. Thank you.

Comment: When I'm finished writing this work, if you accept, I would like to give you credit for helping me simplify my explanation in this matter. Would you be interested?

Comment: I appreciate that, but that's not necessary. I've used very standard facts/results from linear algebra, and many explanations (or similar explanations) can be found in many linear algebra books, or in various answers on this site.

Comment: Thank you again for helping me with this.

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck on your writing.

Comment: Note however that I've only discussed the case of square matrices $n \times n$. The reason for focusing on square matrices is that it is the only case where it's possible to *always* have a *unique* solution (this happens when $A$ is invertible). But for general $m \times n$ matrices, with the two other cases being $m < n$ or $m > n$ (i.e. underdetermined or overdetermined), it is worth asking what happens: What are the possible number of solutions? And why? When does each possibility happen?

Comment: Thank you twosigma. I will definitely keep that analysis in mind when I get to writing about that topic. Presently, this text only addresses standard high school and college level Algebra. Albeit with a more rigorous approach than usual.